# In a REST POST call, what would be the right way to update the component state for 201 created status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have this component with sends a `POST` request to create some data:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    this.state = {
      firstName: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const data = {
      firstName: "Puspen"
    }
    axios.post("url", data)
          .then(response => {
            //update the state here
          })
          .catch(error => {

          })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.firstName}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in the `then()`, I have three options to update the state, if the status is `201 Created`:

1. Take the `firstName` from `data` and update the state
   `this.setState({ firstName: data.firstName })`
2. The response should contain the created resource and we just update the `state` from the `response` data `this.setState({ firstName: responseData.firstName })`

   ```
   //response
   {
    "firstName": "Puspen",
    "_links": {
       "self": {
           "href": "http://localhost:8085/api/v1/user/theCoder"
       }
    }
   }
   ```
3. The `response` would only contain the `self` link to the created resource, then the react component would make a request to that link to fetch the created resource.

In my opinion the, **1st** one is the best. Now extra bandwidth taken, and no extra API calls
**2nd** option would cause the response to take extra bandwidth.
**3rd** option seems worst to me, making an API call to get created data and that also takes extra bandwidth.

How all large websites handle it?

Comment: Response bandwidth is negligible for a small object

Comment: Yes, it's with the small object, but what if it's a complete question/article/answer ?

Comment: Something like that can return meta data and merge with existing

Comment: Could you please post an answer with some details?

Comment: metadata like: createdTime, updatedTime, tags etc?